# Android APK analysis

Tags: malware, android

I got a suspected .apk file which seems to steal my data and send over internet. I want to analyze its traffic. Do you know which tools are suitable to check behavior of this .APK file or check its traffic?

Comment: Tool (product) requests are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options that could come in handy. Our aim, I assume, is to monitor the traffic of this app:

- Route phone traffic through a proxy or analyze traffic. One option for analyzing traffic is using [Wireshark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555403/capturing-mobile-phone-traffic-on-wireshark). Or you could manually set your phone to route through a proxy like Burp sitting on a specific IP and port.
- If a lot of apps are connecting to the internet, it *might* be tough to zero in on just this app's traffic (not too difficult, but tedious if the not experienced with the proxy/MITM tool). In this case, use an Android emulator and debug/analyze traffic just for this app.

Using an emulator could be a quick fix if you're ok with it not dealing with real-time phone data (is it fudging with my Facebook data?), but make sure your choice of emulated ecosystem is right.

Comment: You seem to say that Wireshark is a proxy ...

Comment: @shcroeder: My bad. What I meant was to analyze traffic via Wireshark or use a proxy like Burp.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify.